# Identify rarity of Pantone minifigure

Tags: clone-brands, minifigure-identification

I'm trying to find out if the item gifted to me is authentic and if it is by any chance rare so I can display it well to showcase it. I'm not sure if I have a Lego piece indeed.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to bricks.se. What makes you think this is LEGO? Is this printed somewhere on the piece? At first glance this looks like a cheap clone figure, but without knowing more that might be a misconception on my end.

Comment: Nothing on that figure looks like LEGO. The head, lengh of arms, shape of torso, shape of hips, ... all look wrong. I would say it so clearly not LEGO that just asking is a clear sign that you are very new to LEGO.

Answer (score 9):

Due to the **Pantone** and **Q930-2-1** I would guess it's a Kubrick toy. So it's definitely not Lego.

You can buy it on [eBay](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/163609669698) for $11 Australian (plus shipping).

[image: Kubrick]

[image: eBay listing]

[image: back of box]

Comment: So it's clearly not LEGO, but the question I'd ask would be if it's *compatible* or not?  I.e. similar scale, fits with LEGO pieces, etc.  Otherwise, I'm kind of wondering *why* these were made, other than to show off the quality of their plastic and color selections?

Comment: I have a **lot** of bricks that are *almost* Lego-compatible, but weirdly not quite. So who knows?!

Comment: @RSchulz being perfectly compatible probably would require an extra $0.10 to $0.20 per small set in better manufacturing tolerances and QC.  Cheap crappy knockoff makers can't afford that because like all race to the bottom junk their margins are near zero and their upstream suppliers are constantly demanding to be charged lower prices for the same items.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight Pantone isn't just some crappy knockoff company though, they're pretty well respected as one of the most widely used color standards if not as a toy manufacturer.  Not sure about Kubrick or Medicom though - those sound more like classic bootleggers.  It's a weird partnership to be sure, unless they're just using the Pantone name, possibly without permission, to lend themselves false legitimacy?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman assuming Pantone is involved I'd assume the colors to be as close to perfect as practical; but they're not experts at making bricks and are presumably using whatever molds and QC that their clone brick partners employ for other projects.  OTOH you're right it could be scam from top to bottom.

Comment: I'm not talking bricks that are *close* - I'm talking about bricks that are, like, 20% larger in every dimension.